# Extract specific redundant tag from xml in java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I would like to extract the content of "body" from xml file

```
<row>
<field name="id">28479</field>
<field name="commit_id">53162</field>
<field name="user_id">16</field>
<field name="body">test test test</field>
<field name="line" xsi:nil="true" />
<field name="position" xsi:nil="true" />
<field name="comment_id">390328</field>
<field name="ext_ref_id">524dd257bd3543ae270027f6</field>
<field name="created_at">2011-05-19 01:37:02</field>
</row>
<row>
 ....
</row>
  ...
```

The output that I'm looking for is

```
 test test test
```

how could I do that by using java code?

Comment: Try out an [XML-Parser](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/12/parse-xml-file-in-java-example-tutorial.html)

Comment: Do some research into XPath

Comment: And if you want to use Java and apply a XSLT on an XML, use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604497/xslt-processing-with-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using the XPath API which will allow you to query the XML content, for example...

Based on...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
    <field name="id">28479</field>
    <field name="commit_id">53162</field>
    <field name="user_id">16</field>
    <field name="body">test test test</field>
    <field name="line" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field name="position" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field name="comment_id">390328</field>
    <field name="ext_ref_id">524dd257bd3543ae270027f6</field>
    <field name="created_at">2011-05-19 01:37:02</field>
</row>
```

And using...

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = db.parse(new File("Test.xml"));
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    // Find the "thing" node...
    XPathExpression thingExpr = xpath.compile("/row/field[@name='body']");
    Node body = (Node) thingExpr.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODE);
    if (body != null) {
        System.out.println(body.getTextContent());
    }

} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outputs

```
test test test
```

Take a look at:

- [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/)
- [How XPath Works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html)
- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/)

For more details

Comment: Do you have any idea how to parse the file using String expression extraction methods, because I faced problem on "Unicode: 0x2" which can not be solve only by reading the file line by line and extracting the <field name="body"> content; any help?

Comment: You could pass the `Reader` through a `InputSource` and allow the `DocumentBuilder` to parse the content.

Comment: Would you please provide it with code example please ?

Comment: `db.parse(new InputSource(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(...)));` or some such...

Comment: even with this code, the same "Fatal Error" I received:
          An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x2) was found

Comment: Consider having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622552/parsing-unicode-character-0x2-using-xml1-1